# Houses have disappeared when playing in creative mode

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughter has built three houses now and all three have been lost in a couple of weeks and many hours. Once she died and lost the building which I know should not happen. The other two just more or less disappeared - and you can tell they have gone as the memory in that world is low or zero.

Is it worth deleting game and downloading again - this is clearly, I assume a glitch with her edition.

I assume you can not save as you go along in the iPad edition? It is upsetting for her losing all her work.

Comment: Just checking- you do have the full version and not just the demo, right?

Answer (score 1):

Two things could be causing this

1. You do not have the paid version of MCPE
2. Your daughter spawned far away from her building which would make it seem like it was deleted...